Error in Getting response in POST Api - for large param values - Native iOS
I have below function to pass the params in api call:
func getOrderStatusSummaryParameter(page: Int) -> JSON {
    let page = page
    let pageSize = 25
    let sort = "posted_date"
    let order = "DESC"
    let universalSearch = ""
    let transactionType = ["Sales Order"]
    var brand = [Int]()
    var orderPlacedIn = "last_30_days"
    var orderStatus = [String]()
    var postedDateDefault = 0, postedDateFrom = "", postedDateTo = ""
    
    if let controller = wireframe.advanceFilterController {
        brand = getBrandItemsIdFrom(data: controller.appliedOrderStatusFilterData?.brand)
        orderStatus = getCustomerItemsIdFrom(data: controller.appliedOrderStatusFilterData?.orderStatus)
        orderPlacedIn = controller.appliedOrderStatusFilterData?.orderPlacedIn?.filterId ?? ""
        
        if let postedDates = controller.appliedOrderStatusFilterData?.postedDate, postedDates.count > 0 {
            postedDateFrom = controller.appliedOrderStatusFilterData?.postedDate?[0].start ?? ""
            postedDateTo = controller.appliedOrderStatusFilterData?.postedDate?[0].end ?? ""
            postedDateDefault = controller.appliedOrderStatusFilterData?.postedDate?[0].filterId ?? 0
        }
    }
    
    var paramObject = ["sort": sort] as [String: Any]
    paramObject["page"] = page
    paramObject["page_size"] = pageSize
    paramObject["sort"] = sort
    paramObject["order"] = order
    paramObject["transaction_type"] = transactionType
    paramObject["universal_search"] = !universalSearch.isEmpty ? universalSearch : nil
    
    if appliedOrderStatusDone {
        paramObject["brand"] = !brand.isEmpty ? brand : nil
        paramObject["order_placed_filter"] = !orderPlacedIn.isEmpty ? orderPlacedIn : nil
        paramObject["order_status"] = !orderStatus.isEmpty ? orderStatus : nil
        paramObject["posted_date_default"] = postedDateDefault != -1 ? postedDateDefault : nil
        paramObject["posted_date_from"] = !postedDateFrom.isEmpty ? postedDateFrom : nil
        paramObject["posted_date_to"] = !postedDateTo.isEmpty ? postedDateTo : nil
    }

    return paramObject as JSON
}

Here in above function you can check that there is a brand param and for that brand param If I pass few brands selecting from the list UI, Its working fine.
But If I select all the brands - by doing Select All (total 12000 values) and passing in params for api call, then not getting any data from the API result.. even Api call is successful.
So the issue is for few data its working fine and for all data i.e. 12000 selected data it give me no results.
Note that Its working fine in Web and Postman.. The issue is with native IOS.
What I am missing here and Is there anything am doing wrong here ?
EDIT
The method through which I am not getting data:
    func getBrandItemsIdFrom(data: [Brand]?) -> [Int] {
    var allItem = [Int]()
    if let items = data {
        items.forEach({allItem.append($0.filterId ?? -1)})
    }
    return allItem
}

The method (experimental method) through which I am getting data:
   func getBrandItemsIdFrom(data: [Brand]?) -> [Int] {
    var allItem = [Int]()
    
    if let items = data {
        // Filter items with specific names
        let specificItems = items.filter { brand in
            return brand.name == "La Tierra de Acre" || brand.name == "Dio Cocktails"
        }
        
        // Fill remaining items from the rest of the data
        let remainingItems = items.filter { brand in
            return !(brand.name == "La Tierra de Acre" || brand.name == "Dio Cocktails")
        }
        
        // Combine specific items and fill the rest up to 10 items
        let finalItems = (specificItems + remainingItems.prefix(12496 - specificItems.count)).prefix(12496)
        
        // Append filterId of each item to allItem
        finalItems.forEach({ allItem.append($0.filterId ?? -1) })
    }
    
    return allItem
}


"even Api call is successful", what do you mean with successful? do you get a response and if so what response?

@JoakimDanielson means there is no issue in api response.. getting 200 Success but the data not coming in response i.e. response list data:[] is empty. I am added two methods through which am not getting data and another experimental method through which am getting data.. can you pls check?

I don’t understand, you say you don’t get any data back but the code you added is for handling the result and one of them has data. How can you both have data and not have data?

Can you share the result of the API call in your fail-case? Is the result payload empty

Is the request being made using GET or POST method? There is a limitation on the URL length, appending 12K brands as parameters to the URL probably exceeds the limit. See also the following post on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

If possible use the POST method to send the data to the API endpoint.

what is JSON? Is this part of a thrid party library?
Do you expect to convert your paramObject in return paramObject as JSON
to be of type JSON without using JSONSerialization?
Note, let page = page is completely useless.

@workingdogsupportUkraine typealias JSON = [String: AnyObject]
